# Prevent active character from being expanded in macro argument

Tags: macros, catcodes, write, active-characters

**Goal:** Have an active character not expanded when writing to file

#### MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% == Package code -- untouchable
\def\foo{\@ifnextchar[{\@foo}{\@foo[x]}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\fooaux[1]{\message{#1}}

\def\@foo[#1]{%
  \@foo@delegate{#1}}

\def\@foo@delegate#1{
  (#1)
  \@foo@write
}

\def\@foo@write#1{%
  \protected@write\@mainaux{}{\fooaux{#1}}
}

% == User code -- can manipulate at will

\let\foo@orig\foo
\def\foo@prep{\begingroup
% 1st attempt -- builds but active char expanded in AUX
  \catcode`\*=12%
% 2nd attempt -- error: ! Missing control sequence inserted. l.32 \foo@prep
%  \catcode`\*=13%
%  \def\@dettac{\char46}%
%  \let*=\@dettac
  \global\def\foo{\@ifnextchar[{\foo@ii}{\foo@ii[]}}%
  \global\def\foo@ii[##1]##2{%
    \foo@orig[##1]{##2}%
% 3rd attempt -- error: ! File ended while scanning definition of \@foo@arg@ii.
%     \edef\@foo@arg@ii{\scantokens{##2}}%
%     \foo@orig[##1]{\@foo@arg@ii}%
% 4th attempt -- ! Use of \foo@ii doesn't match its definition.
%   \edef\@foo@arg@ii{
%     \toks0={##2}
%     \immediate\openout14=foo.tex
%     \immediate\write14{\the\toks0}
%     \immediate\closeout14
%     \input foo.tex
%   }%
%   \foo@orig[##1]{\@foo@arg@ii}%
  }%
\endgroup
}

\foo@prep

\def\@catted{
  !!
}
\catcode`\*=13
\let*=\@catted

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Works: *

Work \foo{normal} \& \foo[ok]{works}

Do not \foo{five*four} \& \foo[is expanded in aux]{x*x}

\end{document}
```

The code marked `Package code` is from a third party and cannot be changed. I can only change `User code`.

The package defines `\foo[#1]{#2}` which eventually writes to some file. (AUX here for demonstration purposes.)

The example redefines `*` to be active and expand to `!!`. This works.

The preamble stores the pristine definition of `foo` into `foo@orig` and attempts to cleverly rebuild `foo`, using an outer macro `foo@prep` to provide proper catcode redefinition of `*` to 12 (other) and redefine `foo` within this context.

The MWE contains three attempts.

#### Attempt 1

Redefine catcode of `*` to 12, and redefine `foo` macros, passing the arguments unaltered. This does not yield errors, but expands the `*` as if it were still active.

**Actual lines in AUX file**

```
\fooaux  {normal }
\fooaux  {works }
\fooaux  {five !! four }
\fooaux  {x !! x }
```

**Expected lines in AUX file**

```
\fooaux  {normal }
\fooaux  {works }
\fooaux  {five * four }
\fooaux  {x * x }
```

#### Attempt 2

This attempt leaves `*` an active character and tries to redefine it to a primitive using `char42`. However, this yields an error

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
l.33 \foo@prep
```

#### Attempt 3

Then I tried out the eTeX `\scantokens` command by `\edef`ing the macro argument to `\@foo@arg@ii` representing an expanded, properly catcoded variant of its argument.

But this also yields an error

```
! Extra \endgroup.
l.33 \endgroup
```

which I cannot make any sense of.

[**Edit** fixed syntax error and added attempt 4]

#### Attempt 4

Used token list instead of `\scantokens`. This one yields

```
! Use of \foo@ii doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.63 Work \foo{normal}
                       \& \foo[ok]{works}
```

Interestingly, this resembles the error I get in on the real document most.

Can somebody guide me how to "deactivate" active characters passed as macro arguments?

Comment: Why not: `\newcommand\foo[2][x]{(#1)\protected@write\@mainaux{}{\fooaux{#2}}}`? || The non-optional argument of `\foo` seems to be used for writing only. So why not applying `\string` to `*`:  `\foo{five\string*four} \& \foo[is expanded in aux]{x\string*x}`? || Do you need expansion-protection for `*` also when `\fooaux`/`\message`-command written to aux-file is executed?

Comment: The package code is shortened and does not show processing not essential for the MWE. Therefore, I could not simply inline the package code. Applying `\string*` is a clever idea but becomes burdensome if you have hundreds of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since several years, LaTeX runs TeX with e-TeX extensions and only ***very*** old distributions wouldn't know about `\protected`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% == Package code -- untouchable
\def\foo{\@ifnextchar[{\@foo}{\@foo[x]}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\fooaux[1]{\message{#1}}

\def\@foo[#1]{%
  \@foo@delegate{#1}}

\def\@foo@delegate#1{
  (#1)
  \@foo@write
}

\def\@foo@write#1{%
  \protected@write\@mainaux{}{\fooaux{#1}}
}

% == User code -- can manipulate at will

\protected\def\@catted{
  !!
}
\catcode`\*=13
\let*=\@catted

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Works: *

Work \foo{normal} \& \foo[ok]{works}

Do not \foo{five*four} \& \foo[is expanded in aux]{x*x}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Contents of the `.aux` file

```
\relax
\fooaux  {normal}
\fooaux  {works}
\fooaux  {five*four}
\fooaux  {x*x}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Note: I left the unprotected endlines in the definition of `\@catted` and elsewhere. Please, remove them.

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm! Didn't know that `\def` could be `\protected`